# Beautiful Soup iterate over html tag

Tags: python, html, django-views, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have the following code in html

```html
<section>
    <section>
        <h2>Title1</h2>
        <p>Text1</p>
        <p>Text1</p>
     </section>
  <section>
        <h2>Title2</h2>
        <p>Text2</p>
        <p>Text2</p>
     </section>
  <section>
        <h2>Title3</h2>
        <p>Text3</p>
        <p>Text3</p>
     </section>
  </section>
<section>
        <h2>Title2-1</h2>
        <p>Text2-1</p>
        <p>Text2-1</p>
</section>
<section>
        <h2>Title3-1</h2>
        <p>Text3-1</p>
        <p>Text3-1</p>
</section>
```

As in some sections have subsections and some don't. 
I want to grab the content of sub-sections and sections that don't have subsections
I am trying to iterate over the subsections, so that I can create an Index in scrapy.
I have following code for scrapy:

```
class RUSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "ru"
allowed_domains = ["http://127.0.0.1:8000/"]
start_urls = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/week2/1_am/#/",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/week1/1/",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/week3/1_am/"
]
rules = [
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), follow=True)
]

def parse(self, response):

    filename = response.url.split("/")[3]
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    divs = hxs.select('//div')
    sections = divs.select('//section').extract()
   # print sections.extract


 #class definition for scrapy and html selector

    for each in sections: #iterate over loop [above sections]
        soup = BeautifulSoup(each)
        sp= soup.prettify()
        elements = soup.findAll("section".split())
        print len(elements),'sublength'
        if len(elements ) > 1:
            for element in elements:
                for subelement in element:
                    print subelement,'element'
        else:
            item = RItem() # create Index Item
            item['html_content'] = each
            print each
            yield item
```

Some of the result is correctly formatted, although some sections without subsections are getting broken down into individual elements.

I want each section individually. I mean since 1 section has other sections. I want to loop over these sections and get them individually so I can keep track of loop. Since some sections don't have sub-sections no need to loop through them.

Is there a better way of doing this in BeautifulSoup?
I want the following output

```html
    <section>
        <h2>Title1</h2>
        <p>Text1</p>
        <p>Text1</p>
     </section>
  <section>
        <h2>Title2</h2>
        <p>Text2</p>
        <p>Text2</p>
     </section>
  <section>
        <h2>Title3</h2>
        <p>Text3</p>
        <p>Text3</p>
     </section>
 
    <section>
            <h2>Title2-1</h2>
            <p>Text2-1</p>
            <p>Text2-1</p>
    </section>
    <section>
            <h2>Title3-1</h2>
            <p>Text3-1</p>
            <p>Text3-1</p>
    </section>
```

Comment: You only want to get the `section` which have `h2`, `p` tag in it? what is the type of `each` here? is it `bs4.element.Tag` type object? how did you got the `sections`?

Comment: No I want each section individually. I mean since 1 section has other sections. I want to loop over these sections and get them individually So i can keep track of loop. Since some sections dont have sub sections no need to loop through them.

Comment: make your problem minimal so that others can reproduce it. and state clearly what do you actually want.

Comment: Check the solution and let me know if it helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this approach. It's a generic from the data you have provided.

```
data = """
<section>
    <section>
        <h2>Title1</h2>
        <p>Text1</p>
        <p>Text1</p>
     </section>
  <section>
        <h2>Title2</h2>
        <p>Text2</p>
        <p>Text2</p>
     </section>
  <section>
        <h2>Title3</h2>
        <p>Text3</p>
        <p>Text3</p>
     </section>
  </section>
<section>
        <h2>Title2-1</h2>
        <p>Text2-1</p>
        <p>Text2-1</p>
</section>
<section>
        <h2>Title3-1</h2>
        <p>Text3-1</p>
        <p>Text3-1</p>
</section>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

sections = soup.find_all('section')


for each in sections: #iterate over loop [above sections]
    if each.find('section'):
        continue
    else:
        print each.prettify()
```